# Edittext disappears when i change screen orientation?

Tags: android, orientation, android-edittext

Thanks in advance.

This is my sample code. Whenever i try to run it and change the screen orientation both the edit text disappears and i have to restart the application.
please help me out

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed1);
    ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed2);

    ed1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()                          
    {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {    
            ed2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }); 

    ed2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()            
    {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

        }    

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {   
            ed1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

This is my main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/table"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="25dip"
    android:stretchColumns="0,1" >

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:text="Edit Text 1"
            android:textSize="15dip" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ed1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:numeric="integer|decimal" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/or_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:text="OR"
            android:textSize="20dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:text="Edit Text2"
            android:textSize="15dip" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ed2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:numeric="integer|decimal" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: i have added it please check it.

Comment: you have land-scape layout for main.xml

Comment: i did not get you Samir??????
i want to keep the edit text whenever the orientation changes!!!

Comment: overide on configuartion change in your activity class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you rotate your device your activity restarts, that is why you do not see your EditTexts.

Add this line of XML to your activity in Manifest file

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

Also check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) out to know more about Runtime changes to your applications.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that `void afterTextChanged(Editable)` method is called on your TextWatchers. In any other method, for example `onResume()` maybe, do you set text of your EditTexts programmatically? This might be the cause for it. 
If this is the case, just make them visible again in the place that you restore your previous state.

Comment: I tried your answer but still the edit text are disappearing.
I was using settext for them to clear their values, but still not successfull whilst orientation change.

Answer (score 0):

Hi, try to add these lines to the end of the 'onCreate' method

```
ed1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
ed2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

**Updated:**

Try this, maybe it will help you.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    [...]
    private final boolean isEd1FirstChange = true;
    private final boolean isEd2FirstChange = true;
    [...]

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        isEd1FirstChange = true;
        isEd2FirstChange = true;

        ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed1);
        ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed2);

        ed1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()                          
        {
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {    
                if (isEd1FirstChange) {
                    isEd1FirstChange = false;
                    return;
                }

                ed2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }); 

        ed2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()                          
        {
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {    
                if (isEd2FirstChange) {
                    isEd2FirstChange = false;
                    return;
                }

                ed1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

}